# 'Remote' access via net-use on W7 Home Premium, password required?

Tags: cmd, remote-access, lan, net-use

I'm trying to use the net use command to connect to my other laptop, but I'm running into problems. The other computer is also used by other family members, and so it doesn't have a password on it.

```
 net use \\LAPTOP-NAME * /user:user
```

It then asks for a password, so I simply hit enter - and it does not allow me in.

I read that I might need to alter a setting to allow connection to accounts without passwords.

I was reading [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/243468/windows-command-net-use-failed-when-login-with-a-no-password-account) and thought I had found the answer to my problem, but the Group Policy isn't included in W7 Home Premium.

What setting can I change on Windows 7 Home Premium that will allow this remote (though within the same LAN) connection?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the registry key that controls the behaviour can be located under

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
```

Do you see something named '**LimitBlankPasswordUse**' ?

I would try opening up an "elevated" Command prompt, and do this:

```
reg add hklm\system\currentcontrolset\control\lsa\ /v LimitBlankPasswordUse /t REG_DWORD /d 0x0
The operation completed successfully.
```

Comment: I guessed it was something in the Registry (on the page I linked) but had no idea what. I'll try this now, thanks!

Comment: The Registry key is there, I assume I set it to zero (false). Thanks for your help.

Comment: yes, when the policy setting is enabled, it gets set to 0x1 and when disabled 0x0.

Comment: Ah, I see. And to reverse it I'd then simply change it back. Hopefully this should fix the issue I have.

Comment: Yep, just be sure to run them from elevated command prompt or you will get access denied even if you are an admin.